# Identifying bands of satellite images qgis

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, satellite

I have a series of satellite images and am not sure which satellite took them.
I know there are 8 bands but not which band relates to which spectral color. Here is the metadata of one image :

```
Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
/home/kai/sat images from digital globe/054892521020_01 katchall 15,13 p,m/054892521020_01_P002_MUL/13JAN07045052-M2AS_R2C1-054892521020_01_P002.TIF
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT=(C) COPYRIGHT 2015 DigitalGlobe, Inc., Longmont CO USA 80503
TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2015:12:11 16:13:54
TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION={ bandList = [ 6; 2; 3; 7; 4; 8; 5; 9; ] }
TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE=2047
TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE=0
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1478
STATISTICS_MEAN=257,95138713292
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=157,66542923619
Band 2
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1764
STATISTICS_MEAN=202,60800252642
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=128,2493741809
Band 3
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2047
STATISTICS_MEAN=201,06180054801
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=146,04955395515
Band 4
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=2047
STATISTICS_MEAN=126,90268325806
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=112,31556464568
Band 5
Band 6
Band 7
Band 8
Dimensions
X: 4096 Y: 4096 Bands: 8
Origin
531286,877766
Pixel Size
2,-2
No Data Value
*NoDataValue not set* 
Data Type
UInt16 - Sixteen bit unsigned integer 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
531286.0000000000000000,869574.0000000000000000 : 539478.0000000000000000,877766.0000000000000000
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 2
Band No
2
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 3
Band No
3
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 4
Band No
4
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 5
Band No
5
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 6
Band No
6
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 7
Band No
7
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 8
Band No
8
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

Comment: how about the metadata ? did you take a look already ?

Comment: metadate from (qgis) layer properties was the first place i went. but i could not find which layer relates to which band

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like DigitalGlobe Worldview-2.

The bands are:

```
1. Coastal: 400-450 nm
2. Blue: 450-510 nm
3. Green: 510-580 nm
4. Yellow: 585-625 nm
5. Red: 630-690 nm
6. Red Edge: 705-745 nm
7. Near Infrared 1: 770-895 nm
8. Near Infrared 2: 860-1040 nm
```

To calculate NDVI,  use 5 & 7.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. where in the data did you find it?

Comment: @kwai I use DG WV-2 regularly. The no. of bands, pixel size, naming convention and copyright statement is very familiar. Look in the image directory or parent directory for full metadata